# Removing white space when an image is removed using apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I was trying to remove images from a PDF using Apache’s PDFBox with the following code:

```
//This will clear unwanted images but leaves blank space.
private ByteArrayOutputStream clearimages(ByteArrayOutputStream destinationStream) throws IOException {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(destinationStream.toByteArray());
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    AtomicInteger keepImage = new AtomicInteger(0);
    for (Object pageObj :  catalog.getPages()) {
        PDPage page = (PDPage) pageObj;
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
        pdResources.getXObjectNames().forEach(propertyName -> {
            if(!pdResources.isImageXObject(propertyName)) {
                return;
            }
            PDXObject o;
            try {
                keepImage.incrementAndGet();
                o = pdResources.getXObject(propertyName);
                //we want to retain the first 4 images, others have to be 
                    removed.
                if (o instanceof PDImageXObject && keepImage.get() > 4) {
                    pdResources.getCOSObject().getCOSDictionary
                        (COSName.XOBJECT).removeItem(propertyName);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.save(out);
    document.close();
    return out;
}
```

I was able to remove the image but could not remove the empty white space it leaves behind.

See image for the problem:
[image: See image for the problem]

How do I get rid of the white space the image occupied?

Comment: **A** please be aware that pdf is a format that in general does not support easy reflowing of the content. Thus, you have to analyze the text, understand its form and layout, determine a new layout, and write instructions according to that. Pdfbox does not have implemented that for you. **B** your code does not remove inlined bitmaps and bitmaps attached to Xobjects or patterns. Furthermore, your content streams strictly said become invalid.

Comment: you could share the code you tried?

Comment: Added code I tried out to remove images. @Vinujan.S

Comment: @mkl , updated the post